# integrating the discord api into Angular

Tags: angular, npm, discord.js

So I recently (yesterday) found this npm package for discord: https://discord.js.org/#/, I run npm install on it and it installs correctly. However it does not seem to recognise any of the classes made by the library. I have the library listed in my package.json but I cannot find the way to get it to work...

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as Discord from 'discord.js'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-discord',
  templateUrl: './discord.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./discord.component.scss']
})
export class DiscordComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(new Discord.Client())
  }

}
```

The errors this is throwing all seem to refer to missing dependencies in my project, but some of them seem to be NodeJS which is confusing me. I will post the code on hatebin for brevity, as it would clutter my post up quite a bit. https://hatebin.com/spiirlcopq

My question is, can I use this api in the front-end? or do I need a different api? There is a webpack version but I have yet to find how I can add a webpack to my code and have a tangible intellisense.

Edit: my VSCode does register the package because my intelissense is understanding what I am trying to do and typing the Discord classname gives me access to those classes, but for some reason they won't load.

Answer (score 0):

Discord has [web version](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/topics/web) and here you can read about this build.

**V2 Answer Version.**

You can can use this code to great Discord bot client if put it in your main file. Also you need great your [application](https://discordapp.com/developers). Then you need to great discord server and invite bot on the server. After then you can call fucntion getClienInfo  and they will return all data wich you need, the `game` attribute has many nested options, so I will leave a [link](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Game) to the parameters that can be obtained.
Discord DM link you can watch in browser version. Its like discordapp.com/@me/channels/${userid}

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();
bot.login('your token here');

const getClienInfo = () => {
    let guild = bot.guilds.get('YOUR SERVERID')
    let member = guild.members.get('YOU DISCORD ID')
    let userinfo = {
        avatar: member.user.avatarURL
        username: member.user.username
        status: member.user.presence.status
        game: member.user.presence.game // 'all game data (https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Game)'

    }

    return userinfo
}
```

Comment: I have also seen this build. but am struggling to get it into my angular project. since I dont rly know how to add it in. do I just write the script tag in the component.html and use the code in the component.ts file? because that doesnt seem to work for me

Comment: As variant.

It depends on how you want to use the Discord API and who will have access to the application / site. The web approach will not be able to hide your token, so this is not the best practice. It is better to declare Discrd outside of any functions in order to be able to access it from any environment.

Comment: Right, what I want it to do is show rich presence (So they can see if I am playing a game, online, etc...) on my website along with my name and a redirect to a dm where they can contact me.

Comment: I adjusted my answer based on new conditions, not sure if this is the best option, but it will work

Comment: sweet, thats a clear example of how I can get my data. however, I am getting this ERROR in ./node_modules/discord.js/src/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../package' in 'C:\Users\tassc\Projects\Portfolio\node_modules\discord.js\src'
ERROR in ./node_modules/discord.js/src/client/ClientDataResolver.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\tassc\Projects\Portfolio\node_modules\discord.js\src\client'
i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.

Comment: Make sure you are right install discord.js and have required node.js version.

Answer (score 0):

There might be some merit to the Discord browser js that Cipher is referring to in another solution, however, I have not been able to get it to work either.

I decided to run my own NodeJS server, and then write my API specific functionality there. This does help obfuscate some of the keys I was worried about being on the client anyways. Discord documentation writes on like almost every page to not share the key. Keeping it on server side will help you do that.

Its like getting two birds stoned at once ;)

**tl;dr Run your own NodeJS server and then write an API on top of it that you can call from your Angular Project**